# Does it matter if the executioner extracts a confession from Aryan La Valette?

Tags: the-witcher-2

In the La Valette's dungeons in the prologue for The Witcher 2, if you helped Aryan La Valette escape, he *will* help you flee the dungeon. There are two ways to meet up with him -- the first is by getting the key to open the locked door in the dungeon, dropping down, and interrupting the Executioner's torture session.

Alternatively, if you ignore the back passage you will come upon Aryan La Valette mounting an escape of his own. Presumably, at this point, he has signed the false confession claiming parentage over the late King Foltest's children.

Does it change anything, plot-wise, if you rescue him from the hangman as opposed to discovering him mid-escape?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you never run in to him again.  Not only that, but he and his mother are interchangeable in the plot and neither seem to matter after the escape.

Comment: @Tzenes - it's more a question regarding the ramifications of the confession, and what it might mean for Anais and Boussy (Foltest's heirs or, if the confession is signed, the Baroness' incestuous children (with no claim to the throne))

Comment: I don't believe that is defined in the canon.

Comment: @Tzenes - Well I do know that at one point in Roche's path you need to secure an heir to control Temaria. As I haven't reached that yet, I'm not sure how much (if at all) past events factor into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter.  The plot is unchanged, regardless of whether you meet Aryan in the executioner's chamber, or during his escape.

Answer (score 1):

well.. regardless of what he signs.. you blow up the entire place.. evidence destoryed.. hence, he signed nothing..
im not sure if it was left as an "open" option in the canon or not..
i didnt hear him confessing though.. nor signing anything (he tortured him, 10secs later we were there..)